# Given $f(x)=\frac{x}{2+x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x}$ why does $f(g(x))$ = x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to calculate $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ where $f(x)=\frac{x}{2+x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x}$

The answer in my book says that both $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ are equal to x but I cannot arrive at this.

Here is how I approached $f(g(x))$:

$\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x}}{\frac{2+x}{1}}$ # (substitute x in with the formula for $g(x)$)

$\frac{2x}{1-x} . \frac{1}{2+x}$ = $\frac{2x}{(1-x)(2+x)}$ # multiply by the reciprocal to arrive at the quotient

$\frac{2x}{-x^2-x+2}$ # simplify denominator

For $g(f(x))$ I arrived at $\frac{4x^2+2x}{(2+x)(x+1)}$

For either $f(g(x))$ of $g(f(x))$ I do not arrive at just x. Where did I go wrong?

Here's a screen shot of the question and solution just in case I missed anything:
[image]

Comment: The first expression $\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x}}{\frac{2+x}{1}}$ is already wrong.

Comment: Btw, there is an easy method to find your error: Choose any sample value, say $x=2$. Then compute $g(2) = \frac{2*2}{1-2} = -4$, $f(-4) = \frac{-4}{2-4} = 2$. That looks good. Now set $x=2$ your calculations and see where you get a different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note,

$$f(g(x))= \frac{g(x)}{2+g(x)}= \frac{\frac{2x}{1-x}}{2+\frac{2x}{1-x}} =\frac{2x}{2} =x$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $f(x)=\frac{x}{2+x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x}$. Then we see,

\begin{align}
 f(g(x))=\frac{g(x)}{2+g(x)}=\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x}}{2+\frac{2x}{1-x}}=\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x}}{\frac{2}{1-x}}
=\frac{2x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x}{2}=x.
\end{align}